# AttributeError: Unknown property density

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

I am trying to get a hold of SciPy, but I am stuck with `Unknown property density` error, even though I copied the whole code from official [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

This part worked fine:

```
x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.01), norm.ppf(0.99), 100)
ax.plot(x, norm.pdf(x), 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='norm pdf')

rv = norm()
ax.plot(x, rv.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label='frozen pdf')

r = norm.rvs(size=1000)
```

But the following part gives me the `AttributeError: Unknown property density`:

```
ax.hist(r, density=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That error is occurring in the `hist` function of `matplotlib`.  Which version of `matplotlib` are you using?  You can check with `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)`.  `density` is a newer argument that replaces the deprecated `normed` argument.

Comment: I am using matplotlib version 1.5.1 and back end "nbagg".

Comment: I don't know which version of matplotlib added the `density` argument, but I suspect 1.5.1 is too old.  Use `normed=True` instead.

Comment: You should consider adding your comment as answer down below @WarrenWeckesser. Your solution worked excellent for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I changed the python version from 2.7 to 3.6 and the problem solved.