# matplotlib histogram plot 'density' argument not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try running the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(1000)
plt.hist(x, bins=50, density=True)
plt.show()
```

And I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property density
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? Versions < 2 don't have the `density` argument for hist

Comment: Older question without answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368471/attributeerror-unknown-property-density

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the Python version and matplotlib version you are using?

Older versions of matplotlib (e.g. 1.3.1) don't have the `density` parameter, but instead have the `normed` parameter. This is probably why you are getting the `AttributeError`.

To check the matplotlib version, you can simply do:

```
python -m pip list
```

Versions of matplotlib above 2.0 all have the `density` parameter.